# Change textSize of textfield from another widget Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I need to change the fontSize of a textField by clicking on an Icon which is in another widget. So I have my custom textfield widget here.

```
class StateTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  final Function(bool,Widget) callback;
  final String fontFamily = FontFamily.Arial.toString().split('.')[1];
  double fontSize = 18;
  final Function(bool) selected;
  final bool highlighted = false;
  bool hasFocus() {
    return focusNode.hasFocus;
  }

   increaseFontSize() {
    fontSize += 2;
  }

  decreasefontSize() {

    if (fontSize > 0) fontSize -= 2;
  }

  StateTextField({@required this.callback,@required this.selected});
  @override
  _StateTextFieldState createState() => _StateTextFieldState();
}
```

And in the second widget I used the function increaseFontSize and decreaseFontSize to change the size

```
 onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(widget.textField.fontSize);
                  widget.textField.increaseFontSize();

                  print(widget.textField.fontSize);
                });
              }
```

the size increases on clicking the button but is not reflected. I realise it's because setState doesn't change the state of the textField. What approach should I follow then?

Comment: you should have a global state and that can be done using any state management technique, i recommend you take a look at the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable file and import it to your main.dart or wherever you need it.

```
double fontSize = 12;
```

variable.dart

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    TextField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: fontSize
      )
    ),
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 70,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            fontSize = fontSize +1; //or fontSize+=1;
          });
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text("+")
        )
      )
    ),
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 70,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            fontSize = fontSize -1; //or fontSize-=1;
          });
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text("-")
        )
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

main.dart

Comment: this will work, but it's not a good practice to have a global variable as shown [here](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: then he can just create it as local variable it will also work but only inside the class though

Comment: yeah that's why i recommended using a state management technique.

Comment: anyways I have read the link you posted it's helpful though but I think it's not always bad. you see there are scenarios where global variables are needed for performance and memory

Comment: the problem is that I will add a dynamic number of text fields as per the user's choice. so creating a global variable is a bit of an issue as I will need multiple such variables.

Comment: @AYUSHSINGH you can do that inside your class too, never mind the global stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is this approach which will help you somehow.

**STEP 1:** Do not use increase/decrease method in the StatefulWidget

**STEP 2:** Store the value in a variable and do changes in the same widget itself

```
class StateTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  final Function(bool,Widget) callback;
  final String fontFamily = FontFamily.Arial.toString().split('.')[1];
  double fontSize = 18;
  final Function(bool) selected;
  final bool highlighted = false;
  bool hasFocus() {
    return focusNode.hasFocus;
  }

  StateTextField({@required this.callback,@required this.selected});
  @override
  _StateTextFieldState createState() => _StateTextFieldState();
}

StateTextFieldState extends State<StateTextField>{
   double _fontSize;

   @override
   void initState(){
      super.initState();

      // setting the value from the widget in initialization of the widget to the local variable which will be used to do the increase-decrease operation
      _fontSize = widget.fontSize;
   }

   void increaseFontSize() {
    setState(() => _fontSize += 2);
   }

   void decreasefontSize() {
     if (_fontSize > 0){
       setState(() => _fontSize -= 2);
     }
   }

   //in your widget method, you can perform your operation now in `onTap`
   onTap: () {
     print(_fontSize);
     //call your increase method here to increase
     _increaseFontSize()
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps you in some extent. Thanks :)

Comment: cannot add setState in the widget class. setState can only be called in the State class

Comment: @AYUSHSINGH I have updated my code, please see if that helps.

Comment: the other widget is inside a different stateful widget. How will I access this function inside that widget?

Comment: Show us the full code @AYUSHSINGH then. This much code is not helpful. Thanks